# Running .CMD Script in YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, scripting, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have recently needed to run a .CMD script using YAML in Azure DevOps. I can get it to run and put files in the root of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` but I need it to put the files in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/teacher/website`. Every time I try to do this In two different ways I come up short.

I have first tried with this method:

```html
  Batch script
   Run a Windows command or batch script and optionally allow it to change the environment
  - task: BatchScript@1
    inputs:
      filename: 'scripts/deploy.cmd'
      arguments: # Optional
      modifyEnvironment: False # Optional
      workingFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/teacher/website # Optional
      failOnStandardError: false # Optional
```

This way will just put the files in the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` which is not what I want, as I have some .Net Build files going there.

I then tried this way:

```html
  - script: 'scripts/deploy.cmd' # script path or inline
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/teacher/website'  
    displayName: run deploy.cmd
    #failOnStderr: #
    #env:  # mapping of environment variables to add
```

This way I get an error that says: `##[error]Container path not found: C:\azp\agent\_work\17\a\Teacher\website`

I am trying to build all this into an artefact and then that artefact is later deployed to the web app. Here is my fully YAML file so you have an idea of what I am doing:

```html
parameters:
  - name: buildConfiguration
    type: string
    default: 'Release'
  - name: project
    type: string
    default: 'Teacher.csproj'
  - name: artifactName
    type: string
    default: 'Teacher'

jobs:
- job: 
  pool:
    name: 'DotNet6_Terraform'
  steps:
  - checkout: Teacher  
    submodules: true 

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: make the Teacher Folder 
    inputs:
      script: 'mkdir Teacher' 
      workingDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: make website directory 
    inputs:
      script: 'mkdir website' 
      workingDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher 
  
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Check for folders
    inputs:
      script: | 
         echo '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher'
         echo '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher/website'
  
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: show directory tree 
    inputs:
      script: |
        cd '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Teacher' 
        dir

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: 'Teacher/**/*.csproj'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: checking dotnet versions
    inputs:
      script: |
        dotnet --list-sdks
        dotnet --list-runtimes
  
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: dotnet build 
    inputs:
      script: |
        dotnet build Teacher/Teacher.csproj --configuration Release
   
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Application'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher'
      publishTestResults: false 
      zipAfterPublish: true
      modifyOutputPath: false
      workingDirectory: Teacher 
  
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: List Files Post Publish
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Get-ChildItem -path '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher'
  
  - script: 'scripts/deploy.cmd' # script path or inline
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher/website'  
    displayName: run deploy.cmd
    #failOnStderr: #
    #env:  # mapping of environment variables to add

  # Batch script
  # Run a Windows command or batch script and optionally allow it to change the environment
  #- task: BatchScript@1
   # inputs:
    #  filename: 'scripts/deploy.cmd'
      #arguments: # Optional
      #modifyEnvironment: False # Optional
    #  workingFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Teacher/website # Optional
     # failOnStandardError: false # Optional

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```